# vscode isn't recognizing react's functions import missing problems

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, import, error-detection

It has been a long time since this issue bothers me and I ignored it.
Right now I'm going a little crazy so I decided to solve it at last.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyc9i.png)

Why the hell VSCode doesn't shout at me for not importing 'useState' from React?
This happens for any function or hook...

I've installed ESLint, Prettier and more extensions and nothing works....

Thank you all!